# Compiler for better template support

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

Which of the following C++ compilers is better taking C++ templates (+ error messages issued ) into concern?

- g++
- clang
- comeau
- cl.exe (MSVC++)
- icl.exe (Intel C++)

Comment: Comeau and Intel C++ should for the most part issue the same syntax and semantic error diagnostic messages since they both utilize the EDG frontend.

Comment: Different people have different preferences for the way their errors are reported.  Some people panic at getting 20 lines related to one template error, or want types simplified to their typedef names where possible, while other people like getting maximum detail so they can work up and down instantiation chains and perceive additional aspects of the problem.  There is no single "better" that suits everyone - it depends on your skill level and the complexity of the code you have to write and work with.

Comment: None of these compilers issues better diagnostic messages than all of the others in all circumstances. Sure, you can pick out certain examples and say "look at this beautiful, clear, actionable message that this one compiler gives, and look at the crap error messages that all the others give," but I know that I've seen diagnostics from every one of those compilers that have puzzled me. It's good to be able to compile your code with multiple compilers so that when you do have puzzling error messages you can see what another compiler has to say.

Comment: @James: Totally agree with your last comment. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I prefer Comeau for its conformance with the Standard. Error messages issued by Clang [are more useful](http://clang.llvm.org/diagnostics.html) than those issued by g++.

MSVC++'s compiler is broken [No two phase name lookup].

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Clang and Comeau are better. Clang provides good diagnostic messages.

See these few examples of [Expressive Diagnostics](http://clang.llvm.org/diagnostics.html) by Clang.

I prefer Clang because its free (unlike Comeau).